# Acceleration of a particle

Tags: convergence-acceleration

I have a bidimensional circunference centered in (5,5) made of 1000 points. So the equation that describes the circunference is:
$$(x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 25$$

Imagine that I have a vehicle that is running in that circunference as reaches 1 point for each second. How can I get the speed vector (x and y) and the acceleration (x and y)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I suppose a uniform circular motion. In this case the angular velocity is $$\omega=\frac{2\pi}{1000}
$$ 
so the equations of motion are:
$$
x=5+5\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{1000}t \right) \qquad y=5+5\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{1000}t \right)
$$

deriving these you can find the equations for the velocity and the acceleration.

Comment: Is it $t$ or $t-t_{before}$? Because $t-t_{before}$ is always equal to 1

Comment: It is $t$. What do you means with $t_{before}$?

Answer (score 1):

For uniform (constant speed) circular motion, the speed, $v$ is the circumference divided by the period.  The circumference is 10$\pi$ (in the same length units as $x$ and $y$) and the period is 1000 (seconds).  The direction of the velocity vector is perpendicular to the radius vector from the center of the circle to point $(x,y)$, so $\vec{v}$ is parallel to $(y-5)\hat{i}-(x-5)\hat{j}$.  Therefore 
$$\vec{v} = \pm \frac{10\pi}{1000}\frac{(y-5)\hat{i}-(x-5)\hat{j}}{\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2}} = \frac{\pm \pi}{500}[(y-5)\hat{i}-(x-5)\hat{j}]$$
The $\pm$ sign indicates the velocity could be either clockwise (+) or counter-clockwise (-).

The acceleration has magnitude $v^2/r$ and its direction is opposite to the radius vector.  Therefore
$$\vec{a} = \frac{-\pi^2}{5(500)^2}\frac{(x-5)\hat{i}+(y-5)\hat{j}}{\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2}} = \frac{-\pi^2}{5^2(500)^2}[(x-5)\hat{i}+(y-5)\hat{j}]$$